# CentOS, node cannot find module

Tags: node.js, express, centos

I ran the index.js well on my MacOS.
Today, I use the git&&Github to deploy the node project to the CentOS 7. 
The project shows me the error. 
`node index.js`  I see an error  `Cannot find module 'Joi'`

`npm list --depth=0`

```
npm list --depth=0
nodeMongoVdily@1.0.0 /root/newNode
├── express@4.16.4
├── joi@14.3.1
└── mongoose@5.4.17
```

Who knows the reason?

I searched on the Google and the Stack Overflow half an hour. I found nothing to iron out this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'Joi'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/newNode/model/genre.js:2:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/newNode/routes/genre.js:5:29)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
```

Comment: Your require needs to lower case, e.g `require('joi')`. Your local mac is most likely case insensitive which could be why it's working on your mac but not server.

Comment: @OllysCoding  Thanks, I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On https://discuss.circleci.com/t/error-uncaughtexception-cannot-find-module-joi/24949/2

I found the answer.

> You wouldn’t believe but I change my code from
>   let Joi = require('Joi')
>   to
>   let joi = require('joi')
>   all small-case, surprisingly it fixed the build.
>   But I am guessing y it worked locally :thinking: